# Flask-Admin + (Flask-Login and/or Flask-Principal)

Tags: python, plugins, import, flask

Authentication and authorization can be integrated into Flask via the *Flask-Login* and *Flask-Principal* plugins.  (Or also potentially via the Flask-Security plugin.)

HOWEVER: *Flask-Admin*--another plugin which provides a backend dashboard--is not a registered blueprint...and, I believe (insomuch as I can tell), the decorators used by Flask-Login and Flask-Principal--and that are otherwise required for a user to access a rendered view...those decorators only operate on views that are part of a registered blueprint.

TWO QUESTIONS:

1) How do I register Flask-Admin as a blueprint in my app, and/or otherwise enable Flask-Login and/or Flask-Principal decorators to protect views associated with Flask-Admin?

2) Why do Flask-Login and Flask-Principal work only on objects which are "natively" part of my app...and not objects (e.g., "Admin" object) that is imported from a plugin?  How can I work around this problem...if indeed I am perceiving it correctly?

I gather this is the problem insomuch as it's no sweat for me to create protected views for my app's main index page...or any other page with a view located inside a blueprint.  I just can't seem to do it for the Flask-Admin index page (which, again, has no blueprint).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flask-Admin provides another way of providing authentication - you simply subclass the `AdminIndex` and `BaseIndex` views (or views from `contrib` if you only need those) and implement the `is_accessible` method. See [the documentation](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/#authentication) for more details. There is also [an example](https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/blob/fe6f14e6b7606931d20925a96b4de7cff11447b9/examples/auth/app.py) provided in the repository.

Comment: Thanks, Sean...for turning me onto the docs for this one.  I've reviewed them, and attempted to implement them...albeit to no avail. Use of the is_accessible method then makes it unnecessary to use Flask-Login to protect the admin dashboard?  Meaning: then I don't need a Flask-Login decorator for the def of any Flask-Admin view? I have to say, outside of the repo, the docs are thin for auth with Flask-Admin. If, by chance, beyond the above repo, you come across another public implementation of that solution...would love to know about it.

Comment: @Sean - you don't need the Flask-Login *decorator* but you would need to use the Flask-Login methods to authenticate the user.  If you look at [line 85](https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/blob/master/examples/auth/auth.py#L85) and beyond of the example you'll see that the admin views are only accessible if the current user is authenticated.  If an un-authenticated user attempts to access the admin views they should be redirected to the login screen.

Comment: Can you reshare the example? The github expired/does not work. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Simple example how to use Flask-Admin with Flask-Principal

```
from functools import partial
from flask.ext.admin import Admin as BaseAdmin, AdminIndexView
from flask.ext.principal import Permission, identity_loaded, Need
from flask.ext.security import current_user

PartnerAccessNeed = partial(Need, 'access')

class PartnerAccessPermission(Permission):
    def __init__(self, partner_id):
        need = PartnerAccessNeed(partner_id)
        super(PartnerAccessPermission, self).__init__(need)


@identity_loaded.connect
def on_post_identity_loaded(sender, identity):  
    if hasattr(current_user, 'partner'):
        identity.provides.add(PartnerAccessNeed(current_user.partner.id))

class PartnerAdminIndexView(AdminIndexView):

    def __init__(self, partner_id, *args, **kwargs):
        self.partner_id = partner_id
        super(PartnerAdminIndexView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def is_accessible(self):

        if current_user.is_anonymous():
            return redirect(url_for_security('login'))

        if not current_user.is_partner():
            return False

        permission = PartnerAccessPermission(self.partner_id)

        if permission.can():    
            return True

        return False

class PartnerAdmin(BaseAdmin):
    def __init__(self, partner_id, endpoint, name, subdomain, *args, **kwargs):

        index = PartnerAdminIndexView(name=name, 
                                      endpoint=endpoint,
                                      url='/dashboard',
                                      partner_id=partner_id)

        super(PartnerAdmin, self).__init__(base_template='mcnm/master.html', index_view=index, subdomain=subdomain)
```

Comment: Returning a redirect in `is_accessible` is evaluated as True. That is definitely not what you want!

Answer (score 0):

This [repository](https://github.com/briancappello/flask-react-spa) is a good example of how [flask-login](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login) and [flask-security](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security) can be connected with flask-admin.

In [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/7tr82o/example_integrating_flask_admin_into_flask_webapp/) the author of the boilerplate describes shortly the implementation logic.